# How to get the blue coloring on a long click

Tags: android, listview, textview

I got a TextView in a ListView. I want to make a longClick on this element so I used the "textview.setLongClickable(true)" method this works properly but I do not get the blue colering like on a normal longClick.

I cannot use "textview.setFocusable(true)" if I use this method I cannot use the longClick anymore.

Is there any method or flag that I have to set that i get the blue coloring?

Thanks in advance!

edit: so what I search is something like textview.setHighligting() or anything similar that makes the blue coloring available for the TextView.

in the listview I got some elements where the blue coloring works with the longClick but on that specific TextView it doesn't

Comment: You do not need to use setLongClickable(true) to enable long click function. You just need to assign a onLongClickListener to your TextView.

Comment: I use a ListView with a ListViewAdapter that makes it a little bit more complicated when I use a longClick I want to know on which element I used this click so I can change/delete the selected view. When I set a several longClick event I cannot get the position of the element in the listview I hope this make sense for you. Also the longClick function works already but I dont get the blue coloring ..

Comment: You want to set a longclick listener only on the TextView or in all the list item?

Comment: I use the onContextItemSelected() method in my MainActivity then I use the getMenuInfo() and get the position of the selected item in the listview. Therefore I do not add a longClickListener to every item in the listview.